# Why does the "Registration List" tab not appear for my events for users with adequate privileges?

Tags: 8, rng

I'm using the RNG events module in D8 - when a user with adequate privileges clicks the event tab, they can see and edit all fields, but the "Registration List" tab doesn't show, and they can't see the list of current registrants without the use of a custom view.

This may or may not be connected to the problem I'm having here - [How do I limit permissions to manage an event?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202083/how-do-i-limit-permissions-to-manage-an-event-with-rng)

Comment: The 'Registration List' tab is a view. You cannot see the registrations without it. If you want to see info about the registrants you can add a Views relationship. (type: registrant. Identity to User entities). Typically only the users who can edit a entity are also allowed to edit the events page, and view the registration list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I had installed and was using the Field Permissions module which takes over any and all other permissions set in any of those other places. Once I edited each field on the event content type with custom permissions everything works great.

This still doesn't solve or explain the missing Registration list tab for admin users per [How do I limit permissions to manage an event?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202083/how-do-i-limit-permissions-to-manage-an-event-with-rng) though.

Comment: Are you saying you have never seen the 'Registration list' tab? If this is the case you need to create that view by enabling _rng_views_ module. Then go to the event type edit form. An [option to create the view](http://i.imgur.com/WfeVAvq.jpg) will appear.